# How can I implement all the business logic from views to forms?

Tags: python, django

I am working on a webapp and I want to move my logic in views to forms. In views I only want to keep the checking of validation. That is:

**Example**:

```
def myformview(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = MForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            redirect("to-some-view")

    render(request, "template_name.html", {
        'form': form
    })
```

Here is my **views.py**:

```
def login_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        login_form = Login(request.POST)
        if login_form.is_valid():
            email = login_form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = login_form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
            if user in User.objects.all():
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dashboard'))
            else:
                return render(request, 'todoapp/waiting_2.html')

    return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {'form': Login()})
```

Here is my **forms.py**:

```
class Login(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=250)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

Everything is working fine for now. I just want to move the logic in views to forms. That's it.

**EDIT:**
I changed my forms.py and views.py but its still not working and I am getting a `Page Not Found 404` error.

Here is my new **forms.py**:

```
class Login(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=250)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def login_user(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
        if user in User.objects.all():
            login(self, user)
        else:
            return render(self, 'todoapp/waiting_2.html')
```

Here is my new **views.py:**:

```
def login_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        login_form = Login(request.POST)
        if login_form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dashboard'))
        else:
            return render(request, 'todoapp/waiting_2.html')
    return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {'form': Login()})
```

Here is my **urls.py**:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^index/', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^register/', views.register, name='register'),
    url(r'^login/', views.login_user, name='login_user'),
    url(r'^dashboard/', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    url(r'^logout_user/', views.logout_user, name='logout_user'),
    url(r'^auth_users/', views.auth_users, name='auth_users'),
    # url(r'^authorize_final', views.authorize_final, name='authorize_final'),
    url(r'^assigntask', views.assigntask, name='assigntask'),
    # url(r'^assign', views.assign, name='assign'),
    url(r'^task_list', views.view_task_list, name='view_task_list'),
    # url(r'^delete_task', views.delete_task, name='delete_task'),
]
```

Error I am getting is:

```
AttributeError at /login/

'Login' object has no attribute 'session'
```

Traceback:

```
File "/home/gblp250/PycharmProjects/practice/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/gblp250/PycharmProjects/practice/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/gblp250/PycharmProjects/practice/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/gblp250/PycharmProjects/assignment/todoapp/views.py" in login_user
  48.             login_form.login_user(request)

File "/home/gblp250/PycharmProjects/assignment/todoapp/forms.py" in login_user
  27.             login(self, request, user)

File "/home/gblp250/PycharmProjects/practice/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py" in login
  126.     if SESSION_KEY in request.session:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /login/
Exception Value: 'Login' object has no attribute 'session'
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you want business logic inside of the forms? This seems strange at first and it would be easier to help you if we knew your intention more clearly.

Comment: You are not calling login_user method in your view but you should had

Comment: @Rarblack I called the method right before save() like this `login_form.login_user()` but its showing an error; `Attribute error at /login/: 'Login object has no attribute 'session'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you can override the `is_valid` method (refer to [this link](https://chriskief.com/2012/12/16/override-django-form-is_valid/)) in the form and place your logic there, however, a more appropriate way is to use class-based view `FormView` in views and manipulate it.

Refer to [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview) as a start of understanding FormView generic class-based method. This will ease the process a lot once you understand how to use it.

**EDIT :**

This looks fine overall but still have wrong logic implementations

```
class Login(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=250)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def login_user(self, request):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)
        if user:
            login(request, user) // self should have been replaced by request
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('view_task_list'))//You can redirect to any url
```

Here is my new views.py::

```
def login_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        login_form = Login(request.POST)
        if login_form.is_valid():
            login_form.login_user(request) //just call the method created in the form
    else:
        login_form = Login() //this is for GET REQUEST
    return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {'form': login_form}) //you should return instance of the form
```

Here is my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^index/', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^register/', views.register, name='register'),
    url(r'^login/', views.login_user, name='login_user'),
    url(r'^dashboard/', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    url(r'^logout_user/', views.logout_user, name='logout_user'),
    url(r'^auth_users/', views.auth_users, name='auth_users'),
    # url(r'^authorize_final', views.authorize_final, name='authorize_final'),
    url(r'^assigntask', views.assigntask, name='assigntask'),
    # url(r'^assign', views.assign, name='assign'),
    url(r'^task_list', views.view_task_list, name='view_task_list'),
    # url(r'^delete_task', views.delete_task, name='delete_task'),
]
```

In addition, you must set login and logout redirect URL in `settings.py` since you are usinthe g default `login()` method

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/' //change as you wish
```

Comment: @ Rarblack Then what would my urls.py look like ?

Comment: With class-based views? Or overriding is_valid method?

Comment: overriding is_valid()

Comment: No, since you will use the same form and view with some code splitting. Follow the link I have provided, it has the same scenario as yours.

Comment: Its not working. I'll edit the question so you can have a better look at it.

Comment: I did not override the is_valid(). I dont want to override it. I split the code and now I am getting the error mentioned in the question. What do I do now ?

Comment: Did you succeed?

Comment: No still not succeeded. It is still showing the same error :(

Comment: Edited the question with Traceback

Comment: Did you changeyour code to the updated version of mine? The error says that you are passing Login object which should not be

Comment: Its working now. I will post the answer now. Got to know my mistake from another question.

Comment: Your mistake is in login(self, user) it should have been login(request, user) as I said you are passing some object instead of request

Comment: Yeah you are right. That's where I was going wrong. Everything is in order now.

Comment: Glad!! Don't forget to give credit for help and accepting the solution as answer, so others with same issue can find it easily.